# Python / Pandas - merging two dataframes based in a non-index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I want to join two dataframes. Already tried concat, merge and join but I should be doing something wrong.

```
df 1:

index    cnpj   country   state
1        7468        34      23   
4        3421        23      12
7        2314        12      45


df 2:

index    cnpj    street  number
2        7468        32      34   
5        3421        18      89
546      2314        92      73
```

I want them to be merged using 'cnpj' as a 'joining key' and preserving the index of df1. It should look like this:

```
df 1:

index    cnpj   country   state    street  number
1        7468        34      23        32      34      
4        3421        23      12        18      89
7        2314        12      45        92      73
```

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's use `merge` with `suffixes` and `drop`:

```
df1.merge(df2,  on='cnpj',suffixes=('','_y')).drop('index_y',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   index  cnpj  country  state  street  number
0      1  7468       34     23      32      34
1      4  3421       23     12      18      89
2      7  2314       12     45      92      73
```